# Configuring Request Tracker 4.0 with Apache2 on Linux Mint 14 Nadia

Tags: linux, apache, configuration, apache2, rt

My coworker installed Linux Mint 14 Nadia onto a VM (using VirtualBox) and followed the following tutorial to install Apache, MySQL and PHP: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486. He then used the readme from http://www.bestpractical.com/rt/docs/4.0/ to install Request Tracker 4.0. Both of those went pretty well with very few hiccups along the way from what he told me. Now he's forwarded over the task to me and I'm attempting to get Request Tracker 4.0 configured correctly with the Apache server. Currently I can visit localhost and get the following message:

> It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server
>   software is running but no content has been added, yet.

I also configured it so when you visit localhost/rt you *SHOULD* see the Request Tracker interface, but I'm instead receiving the following page, and this is where I've spent most of my time stumped:

> You're almost there! You haven't yet configured your webserver to run
>   RT. You appear to have installed RT's web interface correctly, but
>   haven't yet configured your web server to "run" the RT server which
>   powers the web interface. The next step is to edit your webserver's
>   configuration file to instruct it to use RT's mod_perl or FastCGI
>   handler. If you need commercial support, please contact us at
>   sales@bestpractical.com.

After a few moments it redirects me to bestpractical.com/rt/rt-broken-install.html. (only allowed 2 links apparently?)

I assume I have something misconfigured but am unsure what. I've been googling and fiddling around with this most of yesterday and today with no luck. It doesn't help that I'm fairly inexperienced with the linux environment, I'm sure.

If I understand how he installed it, he wants to set it up using FastCGI so I visited this site requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/FastCGI and followed the guides there, but the documentation is quite awful and doesn't always line up with my environment, so I've had to put in a lot of guess and check work. I'll provide the code I've added to my config files so you see where I'm at for now

000-default in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled:

```
Alias /rt /opt/rt4/share/html
Alias /NoAuth/images /var/www/rt/share/html/NoAuth/images/
AddHandler fastcgi-script fcgi
ScriptAlias / /var/www/rt/sbin/rt-server.fcgi/
<Directory /opt/rt4/share/html/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

RT_SiteConfig.pm in /opt/rt4/etc:

```
Set($WebPath, '/rt');
Set($WebBaseURL, 'http://localhost');
```

If anymore information is needed, please let me know. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RT docs for [web deployment](http://bestpractical.com/rt/docs/latest/web_deployment.html) give more detailed info for setting up Apache with fastcgi and for running at '/rt'. I think you'll want to initially try using the suggested Apache configurations and see if that gets you past the setup page.

(Note that those docs are available in the RT install as well in the docs directory.)

Comment: Thanks! My buddy ended up following the tutorial on this link and that did it for us!

EDIT:
Forgot link... [link](http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/03/01/request-tracker-4-what-is-it-how-to-install-it-on-debian-squeeze/)